# Google Webfonts with Google Sites

Tags: google-sites, google-webfonts

Is it possible to use [Google Webfonts](http://code.google.com/webfonts) in websites created with [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com)? If so, I'd be much obliged for input as to how to go about doing this.

It looks as though it's possible to add scripts in through the site management (i.e. "App Scripts"), but I don't know if it's best to load Webfonts this way -- and even if it is possible I'm not sure of the best way to change the theme fonts.

I'd be much obliged for thoughts and input.

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Comment: Since you asked, Google have added web font integration directly with Google Sites themselves. You can only use their fonts, but you have over 100 to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

A totally different approach..

I am pointing this out because many don't realize that you are not limited to only googles sites tool set ...as an example you can make your own css/java website on a local folder ... use dreamweaver or whatever.... test the site in your local file directory and browser... once you have it the way you want it to look.... fonts and all..... save the local website folder with all the files to a google drive folder that is shared publicly.  Then get the hosting link for your websites index.html from the detail description of the index.html file that is in the folder that is now on google drive.  Open your google site and add a full page iframe using the hosting link to your website index.html file  as its source.

the local website you created is now live on google sites as your website

Answer (score 1):

Choose "More Actions", then "Manage Site". Choose "Colors and Fonts" in "Site Appearance" section. Choose "Page Fonts" in list of properties. There is "Custom" option by right side and list of fonts. Throughout this list you could find Google WebFonts.

I think this is the only one way to use Google WebFonts on Google Sites. Because you cannot use neither "script" nor to get direct access to CSS of page.

It's only my opinion. If you find out another way, please share it with me. Good luck!

Comment: As of 16 May '14 this is no longer in their interface.  I'm going to dig around and see if I can find another way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Setting button > Manage Site > Choose Themes, Colors Fonts on the sidebar > Click Content Area > Scroll down to whatever you need, then click the theme you want.